# Integrate $\int_0^1 e^{-c x\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Does the following integral have a closed form
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^{-c x\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right)} dx 
\end{align}
for $c\ge 0$.

Comment: have you tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: What is the purpose of computing/approximating such integral? A bit of context would be helpful.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  yes, tried that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I want to find for what values of $c$ the above integral is equal to one and the integrand becomes a probability density function.

Comment: @Boby: numerically, that happens at $c\approx 2.80745$.

Answer (score 0):

You could write write
$$
e^{-c x\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}
=\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{-cx}
$$
But I think the integral has no known closed form.